# Publish Web Application To IIS while having Azure Web Role in Solution

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, publishing, azure-web-roles

How can i still Publish the Web Application to IIS when this web application is bound to Windows Azure Web Role in the same solution.

When I Right-Click and Publish the Web Application, it generates Folders/Files with missing Web.config file.

I'm Not sure if this is the only missing one !

**UPDATE:**

i do have the structured web.config of VS 2012 (debug, release) 
with other web.Debug/Release.config files empty

**UPDATE2:**

I'm Using Release Configuration with the following Transform

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">    
    <system.web>
        <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It works smoothly with me, maybe you have something wrong in your configurations.

Comment: any thoughts what configuration might cause this ?
i do have the structured web.config of VS 2012 (debug, release) with all other files empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a Publish Profile for the Web Application project (right click on the Web Application and use a Local Connection).

- Publish Method: Local
- Target Location: `http://localhost:<port>/`

To publish the Azure Web Role, you right-click on the Cloud Project an "publish".

Also, make sure also that in the properties for web.config, Build Action = "Content" and Copy to Output Directory = "Do Not Copy"

Comment: this is exactly what i do, but the published version does not have a web.config file. i don't know why !

Comment: what build configuration are you using?  and do you have a transform for the web.config for that configuration?  If so, right click on the transform and "preview transform" to make sure it is getting generated correctly.

Comment: No Changes in Transform view except for the Debug="true" attribute. please find my Update 2

Comment: Make sure also that in the properties for web.config, Build Action = "Content" and Copy to Output Directory = "Do Not Copy"

Comment: Thanks a lot viperguynaz. That Solved the problem.
I just found another one that looks like it. the 'rdlc' files are not copied to Output Directory. their build action is 'embedded resources' and 'Do Not Copy'

Comment: please when we finish this thread, add your comments to your answers or add new answer so that i can mark it as an answer to my Question

Comment: added previous comment to solution

Comment: I want u to take the credit, that's why you should edit your answer so i can mark your answer